# File does not exist in SonarQube analysis

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, sonar-runner

When analyzing C# project with TFS 2015 vNext build, I get the following error:

> The folder
>   'D:\Builds_Agent1_work\4\s\System\IPS\Files\Logo\MasterDesigns\Logo_11_Seal_of_Pinellas_County'
>   does not exist for
>   'DEV_ScriptAdvisorPBM_SonarQube:DEV_ScriptAdvisorPBM_SonarQube:9C5E1BB5-E446-45C8-9CE6-5F9896D0D063'
>   (base directory = D:\Builds_Agent1_work\4\s\System\IPS)

I think it's because there is a file called "Logo_11_Seal_of_Pinellas_County,_Florida.png" but SonarQube thinks it's "Logo_11_Seal_of_Pinellas_County".

I tried `/d:sonar.exclusions=**\MasterDesigns\*` to ignore the entire directory where "Logo_11_Seal_of_Pinellas_County,_Florida.png" is located but still same error.

Any suggestions to fix this issue? Thx.

**SonarQube 6.5 C# plugin.**

Comment: Can you find the folder `D:\Builds_Agent1_work\4\s\System\IPS\Files\Logo\MasterDesigns\Logo_11_Seal_of_Pinellas_County` in your build server? Could you please share the entire build definition settings? especially for the SonarQube related tasks?

Comment: D:\Builds_Agent1_work\4\s\System\IPS\Files\Logo\MasterDesigns\Logo_11_Seal_of_Pinellas_County file does not exist. I think it's because it should be correctly looking for D:\Builds_Agent1_work\4\s\System\IPS\Files\Logo\MasterDesigns\Logo_11_Seal_of_Pinellas_County,_Florida.png but because of "," comma character in file name, it's incorrectly trying to find a different file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is tracked by [SONARMSBRU-199](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-199) which was fixed in the Scanner for MSBuild v4.1.

The bug report as mentions a workaround for excluding a single file.

FYI support for MSBuild 12 was dropped in the Scanner for MSBuild v4, so if you upgrade the version you will need to make sure you are using a compatible version of MSBuild.

Comment: Thanks duncanp for the quick response. The link is exactly the problem we're having. Unfortunately, we're still using TFS 2015 Update 3 which has old version of "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild" vNext task which uses older version of SQ Scanner. I may just copy the task to create a completely new one with updated SQ SCanner to fix it. In the meantime, I will try using the workaround of using <SonarQubeExclude> tag.